# Позиция не с первого фрагмента во ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Добрый вечер.
У меня есть три фрагмента, и мне нужно перелистывать их во ViewPager'е.
И, чтобы при запуске открывался сразу второй фрагмент, чтобы к первому надо было листать бэксвайпом, а к третьему фрагменту просто свайпом.

Написал такой код в адаптере, получилась лажа:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            position = 2;
            if(position == 1){
                return new FirstFragment();
            }
            else if(position == 2) return new SecondFragment();
            else return new ThirdFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    });
```

mViewPager - ViewPager, объявленный ранее.

В данный момент запускается с первого фрагмента, вернее, позиция первая, но выводится второй фрагмент. Если листать дальше, то выводится все тот же второй фрагмент. Не знаю, почему.

Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы открыть `viewpager` сразу на нужной "странице" вызовите после того как поставили `adapter` в него:

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(num)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, смог разобраться!!!